# EKS Cluster Name issue || CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, aws-cdk

I'm creating EKS cluster using AWS CDK. I want to assigned clustername as per the environment. We have prefix for each environment in SSM parameter. I'm trying to specifiy cluster name as follows:

**First step- fetch prefix:**

```html
const clusternamevalue = ssm.StringParameter.fromStringParameterAttributes(this, 'clustername', {
     parameterName:'environment-identifier-short'
    } ).stringValue
```

**Second step- create cluster:**

```html
new eks.Cluster(this, 'cluster', {
      version: eks.KubernetesVersion.V1_19,
      clusterName: 'eks-'.concat(clusternamevalue),
    });
```

But cluster is not getting created and throws message in Cloudformation: `Respective role<rolearn> is not authorized to perform: eks:CreateCluster on resource <ClusterARN>`

On checking Cfn template I see that the policy to create cluster is getting created in below way:

```html
Resource": [
                {
                  "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                      "arn:",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
                      },
                      ":eks:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXX:cluster/[object Object]"
                    ]
                  ]
                },
```

I think due to [object object] part , policy is not getting created with correct cluster name. Hence it getting failed. if we hardcode clustername, it will work.

Any suggestion, how i solve this issue? or how i can explicitly pass the role while creating cluster?

Comment: Can you mention in the question which language you're using. And also print `clusternamevalue` when you fetch it. Make sure it's correct data type when fetched.

Comment: Its typescript. clusternamevalue is coming  correctly. I think policy which is not getting created correctly with required  clusternamevalue.

Comment: This smells like a possible CDK bug.  Does the template resource `Custom::AWSCDK-EKS-Cluster`'s `Config.name` property have a proper `"Fn::Join"` value?

Comment: @fedonev I did a synth on the above code in CDK v2.8.0 and got the same issue. The Config.name has a proper value but the IAM role policies have [object Object]

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**  It's the CDK's fault.  The CDK cannot generate ARNs for the admin role policies if `clusterName` is part-string and part-token.  The workaround is to add the policies manually.

The OP code looks fine.<sup>*</sup> CDK is correctly parsing `'eks-'.concat(clusternamevalue)` as the `clusterName` (thanks, @KaustubhKhavnekar!), but is incorrectly parsing the name when it creates the cluster admin role. The [problematic CDK code is here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/38e1fe42d8b30d6afaf4a3ccc90dd15d6a5d8255/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-eks/lib/cluster-resource.ts#L139), where it creates the role resource ARNs on the cluster:

```js
export class ClusterResource extends CoreConstruct {
  ...
  private createAdminRole(props: ClusterResourceProps)
    ...
    const resourceArns = Lazy.list({
      produce: () => {
        const arn = stack.formatArn(
          clusterArnComponents(stack.resolve(props.name))  // does not like string + token name!
        );
        return stack.resolve(props.name) ? [arn, `${arn}/*`] : ['*'];
      },
    });
```

Not sure what the root cause is. A workaround is to manually add policy statements with good ARNs to the admin role, [like the custom resource is doing under the hood](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/38e1fe42d8b30d6afaf4a3ccc90dd15d6a5d8255/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-eks/lib/cluster-resource.ts#L154-L172):

```js
// manually add policies with the correct cluster ARN to the cluster's adminRole

const clusterArn = this.formatArn({
  service: 'eks',
  resource: 'cluster',
  resourceName: clusternamevalue,
});

cluster.adminRole.addToPolicy(
  new iam.PolicyStatement({
    actions: [
      'eks:CreateCluster',
      'eks:DescribeCluster',
      'eks:DescribeUpdate',
      'eks:DeleteCluster',
      'eks:UpdateClusterVersion',
      'eks:UpdateClusterConfig',
      'eks:CreateFargateProfile',
      'eks:TagResource',
      'eks:UntagResource',
    ],
    resources: [clusterArn, clusterArn + '/*'],
  })
);

const fargateProfileArn = this.formatArn({
  service: 'eks',
  resource: 'fargateprofile',
  resourceName: clusternamevalue,
});

cluster.adminRole.addToPolicy(
  new iam.PolicyStatement({
    actions: ['eks:DescribeFargateProfile', 'eks:DeleteFargateProfile'],
    resources: [fargateProfileArn],
  })
);
```

---

* CDK usually handles string-token interpolation without problem, but to be sure I tried manually creating the  `resourceName` value with `cdk.Fn.join('', ['eks-', param.stringValue])` and `cdk.Sub`. No luck - same result.

Comment: I have no idea why you use cdk to manage eks cluster. Imho, I will use Terraform or eksctl at least.

Comment: "At least" :DDDD